# Angular Jest unit test failed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, ts-jest, angular-jest

I'm new to Jest testing in Angular, and I'm facing an issue with one of my component tests. The test is failing with the following error message:

```
Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

I have an EhiExportPendingComponent that uses the Store class from @ngrx/store and the EhiExportCommunicationService. The component subscribes to data changes from the store and the EhiExportCommunicationService. The component code is as follows:

[image]

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tw-ehi-export-pending',
    templateUrl: './ehi-export-pending.component.html'
})
export class EhiExportPendingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    subs = new SubSink();
    gridData: any[] = [];
    orgName = '';

    constructor(
        private ehiexportstore: Store < ehiexportreducer.EHIExportState > ,
        private ehiExportCommService: EhiExportCommunicationService,
        private hostComm: HostCommunicationService,
        private ehiExportService: EhiExportService,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.orgName = this.hostComm.getUser().organization;

        this.subs.sink = this.ehiexportstore.pipe(select(ehiexportreducer.getPendingRequests)).subscribe((data) => {
            this.gridData = data ? [...data] : [];
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });

        this.subs.sink = this.ehiExportCommService.selectedSideMenuOption$.subscribe((selectedMenu: string) => {
            if (selectedMenu.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'pending') {
                this.ehiexportstore.dispatch(EHIExportActions.LoadPendingRequests());
            }
        });

        this.subs.sink = this.ehiExportCommService.pendingDataRefresh$.subscribe(() => {
            this.ehiexportstore.dispatch(EHIExportActions.LoadPendingRequests());
        });
        this.ehiexportstore.dispatch(EHIExportActions.LoadPendingRequests());
    }

    cancelRequest(requestId: number): void {
        this.hostComm.cancelExportDialog().then((choice) => {
            if (choice === 'continue') {
                this.ehiExportService.cancelRequest(requestId).subscribe({
                    next: (): void => this.ehiExportCommService.triggerPendingDataRefresh(),
                    error: (): void => {
                        console.log(`Something went wrong while canceling the request with request ID ${requestId}.`);
                        this.ehiExportCommService.triggerPendingDataRefresh();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subs.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I've written a test for the EhiExportPendingComponent, and I'm using Jest as the testing framework along with @ngrx/store/testing. I've also provided mocks for the EhiExportCommunicationService and HostCommunicationService. The test code is as follows:

```
describe('EhiExportPendingComponent', () => {
    let component: EhiExportPendingComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture < EhiExportPendingComponent > ;
    let mockStore: MockStore < ehiexportreducer.EHIExportState > ;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                provideMockStore(),
                {
                    provide: EhiExportCommunicationService,
                    useValue: new MockEhiExportCommunicationService()
                },
                {
                    provide: HostCommunicationService,
                    useValue: new MockHostCommunicationService()
                },
                {
                    provide: EhiExportService,
                    useValue: EhiExportService
                }
            ],
            declarations: [EhiExportPendingComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EhiExportPendingComponent);
        mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        mockStore.overrideSelector(ehiexportreducer.getPendingRequests, pendingRequests);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```